# How can I set the form name with Symfony formbuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, oop, formbuilder

I am creating a form with Symfony formbuilder:

```
$options =  [
     'attr'   => array('class' => 'form-control',),
     'data' => $data,
       ];

 $formBuilder->add($name, $class, $options);
```

When I look now at my form then the field looks like this:

```
<input name="form[color]" value="#c651a8" class="form-control">
```

But I want to replace `form[color]` with `12345`. The result I like to have is:

```
<input name="12345" value="#c651a8" class="form-control">
```

I tried different things like for example:

```
  $options =  [
           'attr'   => array('class' => 'form-control','name' => '12345',),
           'data' => $data,
           ];
```

or

```
  $options =  [
           'attr'   => array('class' => 'form-control'),
           'name' => '12345',
           'data' => $data,
           ];
```

But I could not find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `FormType` class implent the `getName()` method:

```
public function getName()
{
    return null;
}
```

If you build the form via the `form factory` service to the following:

```
$formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')
    ->createNamedBuilder(null);

$options =  [
    'attr'   => array('class' => 'form-control',),
    'data' => $data,
];

$formBuilder->add('12345', $class, $options);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working very well, I just have one problem. I am using this in a loop `foreach ($fields as $field) {$formBuilder->add('12345', $class, $options); }` and the problem is, that my fields are now empty, I think because of the NULL. Do you have a recommendation?

Comment: Or did I put the function getName() to the wrong place? I put it now to my page repository

Comment: If you use this case (https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes) you have to extend this form class with the `getName()` method. Not the repository